# Подсчет строк на js

Tags: строки, textarea, javascript

Здравствуйте! 
Возник вопрос: каким образом можно подсчитать кол-во строк из `textarea` в `js`?
В интернете искал, толкового не нашел ничего.
Кто может подсказать код?

Comment: вообщем разобрался 
кому нужно вот пример 

<form method="post" action="">
<textarea id="ta" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br />
Введено строк: <input id="cs" size=3 />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function textareaCurLineNum(obj)
{
 var rowHeight = obj.clientHeight/obj.rows;
 var curHeight = obj.createTextRange().boundingHeight;

 return parseInt(curHeight/rowHeight)+(obj.value!=''?1:0);
}

function cleanForm() {
 document.getElementById('cs').value = document.getElementById('ta').value.split('\n').length;
 setTimeout("cleanForm();", 500);
}

cleanForm();
//-->
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('area').value.split('\n').length;
```

Comment: как это использовать? я не селен в js

Comment: Все очень просто смотрите пример
http://jsfiddle.net/RtZjE/

Comment: а как сделать что бы информация выводилась  в <input type ="text"...> ?